# Backbone underscore where inside json

Tags: json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app in backbone where I want to find inside a Json record where hotel_id = 1 for example.

I have done in this mode:

```
 var Room = Backbone.Model.extend();
        var Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model:Room,
            url : "includes/rooms.json"
        });
var RoomView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
            template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),
            initialize: function(){ 
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){
                this.bindRoomToHotel();
                var element = this.$el;
                element.html('');

               // $(this.el).html(this.template({hotels: this.collection.models}));
            },
            bindRoomToHotel: function() {
                allRooms = new Rooms();
                allRooms.fetch();
                rooms = allRooms.where({'hotel_id' : 1});
                console.log(rooms);

            } 
        });
```

I have cut many parts but the problem is inside bindRoomHotel when I make the where function return me empty.

This is my json:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "r1",
    "hotel_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Singola"
  },
  {
    "id" : "r1_1",
    "hotel_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Doppia"
  },
  {
    "id" : "r2",
    "hotel_id" : "2",
    "name" : "Singola"
  },
  {
    "id" : "r2_1",
    "hotel_id" : "2",
    "name" : "Tripla"
  }
]
```

How to find record with hotel_id=1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you don't need quotes round the attribute name, maybe try this

```
rooms = allRooms.where({ hotel_id : 1 });
```

edit: I don't see where you are initializing those objects in the code you have provided, i'd expect to see something like this.

```
var Room = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Room,
    url: "includes/rooms.json"
});

var RoomView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
         this.$el.html(_.template(this.template, this.collection.where({ hotel_id: 1 }));
    }
});

var roomsCollection = new Rooms();
var roomView;

roomsCollection.fetch({
    success: function ( rooms ) {
        roomView = new RoomView( collection: rooms );
    }
});
```

Comment: I have changed it.. always empty!

Comment: is your collection populating properly?

Comment: I don't know.. this is how firebug print it a little bit:r {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
length: 4
models: Array[4]
0: r
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c5"
collection: r
id: "r1"
__proto__: s
1: r
2: r
3: r
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: s